# how to Send PHP Email multiple message

Tags: php

The output in our mail is
example : 10, 20, 10, 11

and we need how to get output,
like 
example :
AA : 10,
BB : 20,
CC : 10,
DD : 11,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $aa = $_POST['aa'];
 $bb = $_POST['bb'] ;
 $cc = $_POST['cc'] ;
 $dd = $_POST['dd'] ;

 $email = $_POST['email']; 
 $email = explode(',',$email);
 $email = implode(',',$email);

 $subject = 'result';
 // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: <sample@sample.co.id>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: ' . "\r\n";
#$headers .= 'Bcc: ' . "\r\n";

#pecah data 
$data = array($aa,$bb,$cc,$dd);
$message = implode(', ', $data) ." <br\>";          

#fungsi email
mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: What does `bla bla` do? Why explode then implode on the same character?or do you want to increment a value on the implodes?

Comment: Where $aa,$bb,$cc,$dd are set?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
 $cpi = $_POST['cpi'];
 $cn = $_POST['cn'] ;
 $asi_1 = $_POST['asi_1'] ;
 $asi_2 = $_POST['asi_2'] ;

Comment: explode and explodee cause for sender to multiple email, when i use explode without implode the php output eror is  "mail() expects parameter 1 to be string " so i use implode

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$message = '';
// Remove email from POST values
unset($_POST['email']);
foreach ($_POST in $field => $value) {
   $message .= strtoupper($field) . ' : ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```